# GCD of $n^3+3n+1$ and $7n^3+18n^2-n-2$ is always $1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

A problem I found yesterday says to prove $\gcd(n^3+3n+1, 7n^3+18n^2-n-2)=1$ for all integers $n\ge 1$. To begin, I used the Euclidean algorithm to observe that $7n^3+18n^2-n-2=7\left(n^3+3n+1\right)+\left(18n^2-22n-9\right)$, so $$\gcd(n^3+3n+1, 7n^3+18n^2-n-2)=\gcd(n^3+3n+1, 18n^2-22n-9).$$ From here, I got stuck however, since the next step of polynomial division involves rational numbers. I observed that the GCD cannot be a multiple of $3$, since if $3$ divides the term on the right, then $3\mid n$, however, then $3\nmid n^3+3n+1$. Similarly, by a parity argument, both terms are odd. Any suggestions for how to finish the problem from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem fails for $n=309$. WolframAlpha says so [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(n%5E3%2B3n%2B1,%207n%5E3%2B18n%5E2-n-2)%20where%20n%3D309). See discussion on AoPS [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1545225s1_gcd_of_n33n1_and_7n318n2n1_is_always_1) on how to find $n=309$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Because both terms are odd, you know that
$$\gcd(n^3+3n+1,18n^2-22n-9)=\gcd(2(n^3+3n+1),18n^2-22n-9).$$
A similar argument works for the prime $3$, and perhaps for $3^2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then,$$\gcd(n^3+3n+1, 18n^2-22n-9)=\gcd(18(n^3+3n+1), 18n^2-22n-9)=\gcd(18n^3+54n+18, 18n^2-22n-9).$$ Using the Euclidean Algorithm again, $$\gcd(18n^3+54n+18, 18n^2-22n-9)=\gcd(18n^3+54n+18-(n+1)(18n^2-22n-9), 18n^2-22n-9)=\gcd(4n^2+95n+37, 18n^2-22n-9).$$
At this point, more repeated use of the Euclidean Algorithm reveals $$\gcd(18n^2-22n-9-4(4n^2+95n+37), 4n^2+95n+37)=\gcd(2n^2-402n-157, 4n^2+95n+37).$$ Once again, $$\gcd(4n^2+95n+37, 2n^2-402n-157)=\gcd(899n+351, 2n^2-402n-157).$$ This approach seems very computational however, any ideas for an easier method involving linear combinations?

Comment: Exactly. Mind the case $9\mid n$ though.